# Set default content type header of Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring

I'm currently using an OAuth2RestOperations that extends the Spring RestTemplate and I would like to specify the content type header.

The only thing I've managed to do was to explicitly set my header during the request:

```
public String getResult() {
    String result = myRestTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, generateJsonHeader(), String.class).getBody();
}

private HttpEntity<String> generateJsonHeader() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    return new HttpEntity<>("parameters", headers);
}
```

But it would actually be great to be able to set that once and for all during the bean initialization, and directly use the getforObject method instead of exchange.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First you have to create request interceptor:

```
public class JsonMimeReqInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

  @Override
  public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body,
        ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
    HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
    headers.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return execution.execute(request, body);
  }
}
```

... and then you have rest template creation code which uses above interceptor:

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfig {

  @Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
      RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory());
      //magic happens below:
      template.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new JsonMimeReqInterceptor()));
      return restTemplate;
  }
}
```

You could subclass `RestTemplate` if you were to have some other specialised or universal REST templates in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my interceptor I added these two lines:            headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

Comment: I'm not sure this is the correct solution. E.g. the `Content-Type` header (which e.g. controlls the encoding) is used before the `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` is even called causing encoding issues for me. Has anybody else observed this behaviour?

Comment: Removed the clientHttpRequestFactory because it wasn't recognized, everything else was the same. But still sending xml for me

Comment: @schneida Agreed. The content type is used for serialization before the interceptors are called.

Answer (score 14):

Since Spring Boot 1.4 you can use the `RestTemplateBuilder`

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Spring Boot, you can just

```
@Configuration
    public class RestConfig {
        @Bean
        public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new HttpHeaderInterceptor("Accept",
                    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())));
            return restTemplate;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Was "HttpHeaderInterceptor" recently introduced in spring? I am using spring boot 2.0.1.RELEASE and did not find it. Might be I am not having correct dependency for this class

Comment: @AshharJawaid according to the [Javadoc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-devtools/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/devtools/remote/client/HttpHeaderInterceptor.java#L33) it was introduced in Spring Boot 1.3.0

Comment: it's in devtools, so not meant for production use