# Default MediaType for Http Requests

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My SpringBoot app makes HTTP requests to external APIs, all of which consume/produce JSON. By default, my app uses Jackson for data-binding, and all HTTP requests (using RestTemplate) have apparently used `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers of `application/json`.

Recently I needed to make use of the Jackson xml data-binding library (not for http data binding), so I included that dependency in the app and it seems that SpringBoot has decided to implicitly use `application/xml` for all outgoing HTTP requests.

How can I configure the app to default to JSON when making HTTP requests  without having to explicitly set it in the header of every request?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem as well.

Comment: @RicardoPieper you could try the [interceptor based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590448/set-default-content-type-header-of-spring-resttemplate)? Have you tried it?

Comment: @RicardoPieper also somewhat personal, but I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57706610/how-to-set-default-messageconverter-to-json-with-jackson-dataformat-xml-added). Identical issue, recently posted, & Brazilian sounding surname =) Is that person a co-worker of yours?

Comment: @buræquete This would not work. We have many instantiations of RestTemplate spread throughout many repositories that are loaded during runtime (we do hot-reload), each one of them have some initialization code, which involves essentially writing `new RestTemplate()` at some point. I just wish it would keep choosing to do JSON instead of XML :(
And no, I don't know that guy, but I'll look his question to see if anything comes up. He posted it some days ago, and I just discovered I have this issue like 10min ago.

Comment: @RicardoPieper you can have some XML-based RestTemplates, and some JSON-based ones, and the JSON-based ones' init logic would always include that interceptor add logic. Wouldn't that work? + lol what coincidence then, I was sure that you guys were in same company! I though he was the plebeian dev, and the issue was escalated to the more senior dev after couple weeks

Comment: @buræquete I don't understand what you mean...but it does seem that I will have to go through each one of my repositories and change each RestTemplate manually, either adding a content type header or configuring the RestTemplate itself. This is far from ideal...

Comment: @RicardoPieper repository meaning different apps, modules? If so yeah that would be cumbersome. But all those modules are loaded into the main app, and the xml-dependency is poisoning them all to use XML content type header, is that a correct summary?

Comment: @buræquete Yes, exactly. We've been relying on RestTemplate producing JSON, maybe we shouldn't have?

Comment: @buræquete right now we're going through each project. We figured out a way to know in advance which ones need review. In the end, I guess there is no solution for us. Bounty still open though :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The answer is mostly focused on @RicardoPieper's case, but the single `RestTemplate` case (from OP) can still use [*this intercept based solution*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590448/set-default-content-type-header-of-spring-resttemplate)

In my opinion, it is best to be explicit, and not depend on the `Content-Type` setting in any `RestTemplate`. So set your header values for all calls like;

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<Post> entity = new HttpEntity<>(post, headers);
ResponseEntity<Post> response = someTemplate.postForEntity(uri, entity, Post.class);
```

---

But for your case, I came up with an idea, again doing the intercept solution but from a higher perspective (though it has an assumption still)

Have a listener for context refresh event;

```
@Component
public class MyListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private Map<String, RestTemplate> templates;

    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        templates.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(this::isJsonBased)
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .forEach(template -> template.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new JsonMimeInterceptor())));
    }

    private boolean isJsonBased(Map.Entry<String, RestTemplate> entry) {
        return entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains("json");
    }
}
```

Here I am getting all `RestTemplate` beans in the context (with their bean names included, using the [Map autowire feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58022872/getting-qualifier-names-from-initialized-bean-objects)), and doing a filter first, though this is the assumption part, I thought having `"json"` in the name of the `JSON` focused `RestTemplate` beans, like;

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate jsonTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

and apply the intercept logic to all those beans.

```
public class JsonMimeInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return execution.execute(request, body);
    }
}
```

What do you think? =) It worked on my demo app, though there needs to be some way to distinguish between `XML` based, and `JSON` based `RestTemplate` beans. If you can create such a distinction, you can add that logic in the `isJsonBased()` method and still use this idea!

Comment: I'm giving you the bounty for the following reasons: 1 - You invested your time; 2 - Showed that there is no immediate solution for my problem; 3 - perfectly answered OP's question; 4 - Showed effective use of spring events, interceptors and DI, lots of information condensed in a single post that I'll definitely use as a reference. I forgot to mention that those modules do not know Spring exists and aren't even not instantiated by Spring DI... but in part this is a lie, since they use RestTemplate anyway. This whole thing revealed a coupling that we weren't entirely aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Simply override and configure the default content type in `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter#configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer)` as shown below:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that already and it didn't work. Outgoing requests still seem to be sent with Content-Type `application/xml`. The external APIs are responding back with a 415 code. When I look at the http message converters in the `RestTemplate` object, they are the xml ones from fasterxml instead of the json ones. I assume that I need to configure those as well somehow.