# Getting qualifier names from initialized bean objects

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have two beans of the same type;

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate jsonTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate xmlTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

And I autowire both beans into a list as follows;

```
@Autowired
private List<RestTemplate> templates;
```

The list `templates` will have both beans inside with `size=2`.

From this list, how can I get their names (`["jsonTemplate", "xmlTemplate"`])?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was really simple...

> Just doing;
>
> ```
> @Autowired
> private Map<String, RestTemplate> templates;
> ```
>
> will let Spring to insert the names as keys and the beans themselves as the values in
>   the map.

It seems Spring just stops keeping track of the naming after the injection. So I don't know if there is any other way (or, if even possible, simpler way) than this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use map of beans:

```
@Bean
public Map<String, RestTemplate> templateMap(RestTemplate jsonTemplate, RestTemplate xmlTemplate) {
    Map<String, RestTemplate> map = new HashgMap<>();
    map.put("jsonTemplate", jsonTemplate);
    map.put("xmlTemplate", xmlTemplate);
    return map;
}

@Autowired
private Map<String, RestTemplate> templates;
```